# How to determine the number of bytes read from buffer passed to node.js zlib.inflate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib

I have a node.js Buffer instance, where the buffer is a concatenation of sections, and each section has a 20 byte header followed by deflated data.

What I need is to read the deflated data using node.js, and know how many bytes the deflated sequence had so I can properly advance to the next buffer section. Something like this:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var sections = [];
// A variable named 'buffer' is declared pointing to the Buffer instance
// so I need to read the first section, then the second section etc.
buffer = buffer.slice(20); // skip the 20-byte header
zlib.inflate(buffer, function(err, inflatedData) {
  sections.push(inflatedData);
});
// How many bytes zlib readed from the buffer to
// create the 'inflatedData' instance?
// suppose the number of bytes read is pointed by the variable 'offset',
// then I could do this to read the next section:
buffer = buffer.slice(offset + 20);
zlib.inflate(buffer, function(err, inflatedData) {
  sections.push(inflatedData);
});
```

Comment: I don't think that data is exposed anywhere. Zip expects `buffer` to contain ALL of the data, so it has no concept of letter the user know where it stopped. Why do you need to use one buffer for all this?

Comment: The buffer doesn't really matter, what I need is to parse compressed data that is mixed with uncompressed data. To advanced positions properly I need to know the length of the compressed sequences, which can only be done by parsing it. Since zlib already does the parsing I would rather use it to get that information instead of re-implementing it on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS documentation is not clear. Just add: `{ info: true }`, and the return object will be an object with a buffer with the decompressed data, and an engine. Eg:

```
const result = zlib.inflateRawSync(compressed, { info: true } as any) as any;
const bytesRead = result.engine.bytesWritten;  // "bytesWritten" is actually "compressedSize".
```

If using typescript, you'll need to cast to "any", because @types/node@14 does not specify this option yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
// How many bytes zlib readed from the buffer to
// create the 'inflatedData' instance?
```

Answer: All of them.

`buffer.slice(20)` will be from position 20 until the end of the buffer.  That's what the `zlib.inflate()` method got, so that's what it processed.

Maybe this would be helpful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

You seem like you might be confused.  What are you actually trying to do?  (That is, what problem are you trying to solve?)

Comment: Yes I understand how buffer.slice works, but zlib will only read bytes until the end of the deflated sequence as it has a fixed size. The problem I'm trying to solve is(maybe this would also have been a better title): 'how to parse a node.js buffer that contains deflated data mixed with other data?'. After reading the sources of zlib.js and zlib docs I think the answer is that it is not currently possible since node.js binding doesn't expose the information needed for that. If you wish to give me the answer I will accept it